# Taskkill a process with space in its image name

Tags: cmd, process, taskkill

I'm trying to kill a window 7 32 bit application using taskkill command but I'm having an issue passing a space for the name of the process.

taskkill /F /IM ABC DEFG.exe

If someone could help me with this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Open a cmd window and run `cmd /?` to get displayed the help for Windows command processor. On last help page is written: __The special characters that require quotes are: space and__ ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~``. Next run `taskkill /?` to get output the help for this command. The help contains also examples which contain argument strings containing a space and for that reason those argument strings are enclosed in `"` (straight double quote). Last I suggest that you try if the application terminates also without usage of `/F` to terminate by itself instead of killing it by the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Below Command to terminate any thread use like command and give application alias in between two % %**

```
wmic Path win32_process Where "CommandLine Like '%XYZ%'" Call Terminate
```